# VSCode exit superuser mode

Tags: visual-studio-code, root, superuser

I am new to VSCode (switching from Sublime) and I accidentally caused VSCode to boot up in superuser mode each time I open the app, how do I exit out and go back to zsh or bash? I am not familiar with how to change settings in VSCode.

So far, I tried changing the settings like so to zsh,

[image: Settings in VS Code]

But what this does is that it still first loads as root, then runs zsh within root. I know it's very bad to run root in this way. Any suggestions?